# Macro excel to replace cells

Tags: excel, vba

I've never done some macro and i've to make a vb macro.
my macro must loop all rows of a sheet then look in an other sheet if the value of the "B" cell is found and if yes, i've to replace the value by the matched value in the side column.

As i've never done this, i don't know how to start.
Someone has already done something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a macro that seems working but it doesn't replace the value of the link

```
Sub ReplaceLink()

Dim searchedString As String, replaceString As String
Dim hLink As Hyperlink

'loop shhet
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each hLink In sh.Hyperlinks
        'searched address
        searchedString = Replace(hLink.Address, " ", "%20")
        'new url
        replaceString = NewUrl(searchedString)
        'Search for the specified text

        If Not IsEmpty(replaceString) Then
            hLink.Address = Replace(hLink.Address, hLink.Address, replaceString)
        Else
            hLink.Range.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next hLink
Next sh
```

End Sub

Function NewUrl(searchedString As String) As String
    Dim MyPath$, MyWB$
    Dim GCell As Range

```
MyPath = "C:\temp\"
'The name of the workbook in which to search.
MyWB = "migration_link.xls"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyWB
'Set GCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(searchedString)
Set GCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(searchedString)
'if a matching is found, set new url
If Not GCell Is Nothing Then
    NewUrl = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & GCell.Row)
Else
    NewUrl = ""
End If
```

End Function

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is where to start.

It should be enough to get you going in the right direction.